# Hartshorne's connectedness theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

A key step in proving Hartshorne's connectedness theorem is the following:

> Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring such that $\operatorname{depth}R\geq 2$. Then $U=\operatorname{Spec}R\setminus \{\mathfrak m\}$ is connected.

What does the conclusion of this theorem say algebraically?

Note: The hypothesis has a condition on depth, which is an algebraic condition. Now i know that for a commutative ring with unit, $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is connected iff $R$ has no non-trivial idempotents. But here, we are removing a point, so how does this translate back to the ring in question?

Comment: Have you looked at books on local cohomology?

Comment: @Youngsu, yes, but i cannot find a good answer for the question above. You can reply in terms of local cohomology if you have an answer.

Comment: well, which books have you looked at? Does it include 24-hours of local cohomology?

Comment: Do you mean Remark 15.4 on page 154? I was hoping for more, but i guess one cannot hope for more. I will try to see what this gives me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that $(R,\mathfrak m)$ is a Noetherian local ring with $\dim R\ge 1$. Then $U=\operatorname{Spec}R\setminus \{\mathfrak m\}$ is disconnected if and only if the set of minimal primes of $R$ can be partitioned into two subsets $\{\mathfrak p_1,\dots,\mathfrak p_t\}$ and $\{\mathfrak p_{t+1},\dots,\mathfrak p_n\}$ such that $\sqrt{\mathfrak p_i+\mathfrak p_j}=\mathfrak m$ for $i\le t$ and $j>t$. ([This book](http://books.google.ro/books?id=PMgWho0eq1MC&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=ideals+and+reality+rao+disconnected+zariski+topology&source=bl&ots=dWs6_WIzkJ&sig=szPUAHgQ3vr-QThDbDGXz5GIJ0o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ng-_UofOCcbesgaV4oHgAg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ideals%20and%20reality%20rao%20disconnected%20zariski%20topology&f=false) can be a good reference.)

Comment: I like this characterization. I did not remember this being in there. I remember it having lot of typos, but also heard that a corrected edition is coming out sometime soon. Thanks

Comment: Now your answer has made me more curious. Do you know of any good descriptions for other specific $U$, i mean here $U=\operatorname{Spec}R\setminus \{m\}$. Any reference would be appreciated if you know and dont have time to put it down. thanks

Comment: @user114539 Well, the punctured spectrum is well known, but for other sets I don't know.